# Is there an error in tenses here?

Tags: past-tense

"Your (*noun*) was (*past test verb*) before it was (*different past tense verb*)"

OR

"Your (*noun*) is (*past test verb*) before it was (*different past tense verb*)"

The second one sounds more natural to me, but I'm not quite certain. Perhaps they are both wrong and there is an even better phrase to use.

Comment: It's easier to deal with these questions if you give a specific example.  But in general the past tense verbs will require *was* rather than *is.*

Comment: What does that even mean?  Your noun was/is a verb?  huh?

Comment: @KristinaLopez s/he is just giving the part of speech that you should fill in with words, like mad libs.

Comment: OH!  That makes sense now! lol!  Thanks @RK01!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first clause happened BEFORE the second clause, as is the case in your example, then it must be in the past tense.

EDIT: What I said isn't always true.

You could say "it will get worse, before it gets better.", where the first part isn't in the past tense, but this example doesn't apply in your case where the second clause happened in the past. Since in your case 1) the second part happens in the past and 2) the first part happens BEFORE the second part, then 3) the first part must also happen in the past.

Answer (score 1):

My book was printed before it was sold.

Both events happened in the past.  Simple past tense will do.

Note that past perfect ("had been printed") is not needed, even though the "before" evinces a time difference between "printed" and "sold".